# Why can't I do this in delphi? Do I have to get this error? [Exception EAccessViolation]

Tags: oop, delphi

I've just started developing with Delphi. I just wanted to work with the object. The structure I made is simple. Is there a point I missed?

1. I created a class in a unit called `Unit2`.

   a. I created a string variable in this class I created (in Public section).
2. I added `Unit2` to the uses section in `Unit1`.

   a. I reached the global variable in `Unit2` and changed its value.
3. I added `Unit2` to `Unit3` where I created it.

Now I'm trying to access this data I changed from `Unit3`.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  Gazi = class
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    RektorAdi : String;
    { public declarations }
  end;

implementation

end.
```

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  ..., Unit2, Unit3;

type
  .. (Form Creating)
 
var
  (Form create)

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  newElement: Gazi;
begin
  newElement.RektorAdi := 'Pala';
  Label1.Caption := 'Successfully';
  Form3.Show;
end;

end.
```

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  ... , Unit2;

type
  (Form creating codes)

var
  (Form codes)

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  access: Gazi;
begin
  Label1.Caption := access.RektorAdi;
end;

end.
```

I expect the output of `'Pala'`  (my change to the `Unit1`) but the actual output is `'册['`. I don't even know what language my results are.

In addition to all this, when I try to close the program, I get an error:

> Exception EAccessViolation in module Project1exe at 0000848F. Access violation at adress 0040848F in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of adress 3BC03BBC.

Comment: There's plenty wrong with this code. For a start, your Gazi class doesn't have a constructor. Everything else follows from that.

Comment: I am changing the Rector variable of the experienced class in a single volume and I can access the Rector variable, but I get this error when accessing from another volume.

Comment: Are both units trying to access the variable at the same time?

Comment: Why does Unit3 read the value in the variable as 册[?

Comment: Hi cihatpala, do grasp the concept of working with classes? Please read http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi).
You need to create your class: ie newElement:= Gazi.Create;

Comment: @cihatpala What other languages have you programmed in?

Comment: @nolaspeaker: All classes have a .Create constructor defined in the "root object" TObject that all classes inherits from. You therefore don't need to define your own constructor if you don't need a parameterized version of a constructor.

Comment: I have worked with object oriented c # and java @nolaspeaker

Comment: In C# you'd get the same problem, as you don't instantiate the classes (Delphi Gazi.Create, C# new Gazi), and seem to expect that one local variable can be the same as another local variable in a completely different method. If you are accustomed to C# try making the same code in there and solve the issues you encounter, then you'll probably be able to easily convert your code to Delphi (after all, both Delphi and C# was "created" by the same guy, so they share a lot of similar ideas).

Comment: @HeartWare You are right. I think I'm gonna have a hard time getting used to the delphi syntax. I need some more work in Delphi. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unit1, you are not instantiating the `newElement` object before writing to its `RektorAdi` member, so you are trashing random memory.

In Unit3, you are not instantiating the `access` object before accessing its `RektorAdi` member, so you are reading from invalid memory.

To do what you are attempting (set the `RektorAdi` value in one unit and then access it in another unit), you need a singleton object that both units can share, eg:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  Gazi = class
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    RektorAdi : String;
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  GlobalGazi: Gazi;

implementation

initialization
  GlobalGazi := Gazi.Create;
finalization
  GlobalGazi.Free;

end.
```

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  ...;

type
  .. (Form Creating)

var
  (Form create)

implementation

uses
  Unit2, Unit3;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GlobalGazi.RektorAdi := 'Pala';
  Label1.Caption := 'Successfully';
  Form3.Show;
end;

end.
```

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  ...;

type
  (Form creating codes)

var
  (Form codes)

implementation

uses
  Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := GlobalGazi.RektorAdi;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you for your simple and descriptive corrections.

Answer (score 1):

```
type
  Gazi = class
         private
           { private declarations }
         public
           { public declarations }
           RektorAdi : String;
        end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var newElement: Gazi;
begin
  newElement.RektorAdi :='Pala';
  Label1.Caption := 'Successfully';
  Form3.Show;
end;
```

You don't instantiate (allocate) the space needed for the "newElement" class. All classes must be created by calling a constructor, which instantiates (allocates and initializes) the variable to point to the proper class.

You'll need to do this:

```
  newElement := Gazi.Create;
  newElement.RektorAdi :='Pala';
```

Now, this will ensure that you don't get the access violation when you attempt to assign a string to the member field RektorAdi, but it doesn't solve the problem altogether.

newElement is a LOCAL variable, which means that it is only visible (and accessible) from within the method (PROCEDURE) "TForm1.Button1Click" where it is defined. The variable "access" in TForm3.Button1Click is an entirely different variable (not because it is named differently, but because it is defined as a LOCAL variable in a completely different method). Also, this variable has not been instantiated either, so it is also in an undefined state, which will most likely lead to an access violation there, as well.

You seem to lack some basic understanding on variables, scopes and how to pass values from one method to another, which is beyond the scope of stackoverflow to provide, but here at least is a beginning as to why you get the access violation.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Gazi should look like that:

```
TGazi = class
private
  { private declarations }
  FRektorAdi: String;

  function GetRektorAdi: String; //getter
  procedure SetRektorAdi(value: String); // setter
public
  { public declarations }
  constructor Create;

  property RektorAdi: String read GetRektorAdi write SetRektorAdi;
end;

implementation

constructor TGazi.Create;
begin

end;

function TGazi.GetRektorAdi: String;
begin
    Result := FRektorAdi;
end;

procedure TGazi.SetRektorAdi(value: String);
begin
    if (value <> FRektorAdi) then
        FRektorAdi := value;
end;

end.
```

Then the Unit2 can access its value like that:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var newElement: TGazi;
begin
    try
      newElement := TGazi.Create;
      newElement.RektorAdi := 'Pala';
      ...
      Label1.Caption := newElement.RektorAdi;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(newElement);
    end;
end;
```

outside this event (Button1Click) the class will not be accessible any more, as you have destroyed it in the end. So Unit3 can not get the actual value 'Pala'.